# WordPress - Pagination Not Working on Custom Loop

Tags: wordpress

I've searched and searched and have not solved my problem. I seems like there are solutions but they are not working for my particular code.

What I would like to do is to have two loops - one that calls up the most recent post and acts as the main "featured post". Second is simply the second most recent post that is styled differently - then below the second or "sub post" I would like pagination.

Problem is... the pagination does not work. The numbers show up, but when I click on them nothing happens. Would appreciate any help!

Here is the code...

```
<div id="featuredpost">

  <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&cat=4');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <span class="subposttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span><br>
        <small>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> on <?php the_time('l, F jS') ?>.</small>
<br><br>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
<br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<div id="subposts">

<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&offset=1&cat=4');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <span class="subposttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span><br>
        <small>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> on <?php the_time('l, F jS') ?>.</small>
<br><br>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<center>
<?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
</center>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass multiple properties to wp_query as an array:

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 4));
```